# Proteger Class para namespace c#

Tags: c#, unity3d, namespace

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em C# para Unity 3D onde ele irá gerenciar diversos tipos de banco de dados (Mysql, Postgress...), o problema é que tenho classes que manipulam cada tipo de banco de dados dentro do meu namespace, que são utilizadas por diversas outras classes, o problema que estas classes não quero seja instanciada fora do meu namespace, mas dentro queria que fosse livre o uso. No java, bastava dizer que era protected que estava tudo bem, mas não é bem assim que funciona do C#. Exemplo em Java:

```
namespace MDC {
    protected class Mysql {
         public Mysql(){}
    }

    public class Database {
         public Database(){
               new Mysql(); // Sucesso
         }
    }
}

public class MainClass {
      public static void Main (string[] args) {
            new Database(); // Sucesso
            new Mysql(); // Erro
      }
}
```

Comment: Acontece erro por que a _MainClass_ não está no namespace _MDC_.

Comment: O erro é o que eu quero que ocorra no C#, mas isso não ocorre pois não tem como eu declara uma Class como protected.

Answer (score 2):

Resolvi o problema do seguinte modo. Utilizei o tipo Internal no lugar de protected, como eu irei disponibilizar somente a DLL da biblioteca, quem for implementa-la não poderá instanciar ou ter acesso a classes Internal, pois somente dentro do assembly irá ter acesso a esta class. Ficou assim:

```
namespace MDC {
    internal class Mysql {
         public Mysql(){}
    }

    public class Database {
         public Database(){
               new Mysql(); // Sucesso
         }
    }
}

public class MainClass {
      public static void Main (string[] args) {
            new Database(); // Sucesso
            new Mysql(); // Erro
      }
}
```

Comment: Além do modificar `internal` tem também o `protected internal` que suas classes derivadas tem acesso e somente dentro do mesmo assembly `https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms173121.aspx`

Answer (score 1):

Use o modificador [`private`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/st6sy9xe.aspx), caso queira que a classe seja visível para diferentes assemblies, use [`internal`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/7c5ka91b.aspx).